# User permissions to authorize AWS CLI via metadata inside EC2

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, ansible

I'm trying to get access from my EC2 instance to S3 bucket via CLI, but I cannot do this with my user.

The instance is build with ansible and got 2 users one is `ec2-user` and the other `test-user`. When connecting to the instance via SSH and user `ec2-user` I can easily download the files from s3 bucket, but when logging with the second user I got `An error occurred (403) when calling the HeadObject operation: Forbidden`.

What permissions should I gave the test-user to be able to get data from bucket?

Comment: The best way would be to use instance role to s3. Have you considered that?

Comment: I've already got role attached to the instance with permissions to S3. The problem is with two users on instance. The root one - `ec2-user` can download data from S3, but the other one - `test-user` is not able to. And here is the question what ec2-user have access to authorize CLI that test-user lacks.

Comment: It should work indeed. Are you sure that the second user does not have other credentials, e.g. through env variables or some profiles in `~/.aws`?

Comment: That was it. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comments.

The instance using [instance role](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/batch/latest/userguide/instance_IAM_role.html), thus both users have equal access to s3. However, the access was failing for `test-user` since the user was using **different IAM credentials** then those from instance role.

The credentials came from env variables or `.aws/` which have **higher priority** then instance role, resulting in access deny.